# Find item in Enumerable with the maximum property value

Tags: c#, foreach, max, enumerable

I'm writing an entry for an AI competition in C#, and I'm looking for a more elegant way to search for items. (I'm much more familiar with embedded C programming, but I prefer C# for an AI contest.)

The contest server is using dmcs to compile entries, which is .Net framework 4.0; I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for my testing.

I'm trying to search for an item in a list with the maximum value of a parameter that also meets a certain prerequisite. I don't want the maximum value, though, I want the item that has said maximum value.

Here's my original code that does what I want using a foreach loop:

```
List<Region> myList = new List<Region>();

// ...
// myList gets populated with elements
// ...

Region biggest = null;
int biggestSize = -1;

foreach (Region r in myList)
{
    // We only want elements that are eligible for expansion
    if (r.EligibleForExpansion())
    {
        if (r.Size > biggestSize)
        {
            biggest = r;
            biggestSize = r.Size;
        }
    }
}

return biggest; // I want the biggest Region, not the Size of the biggest region.
```

I'm trying to find a more elegant way to do this so I don't have foreach loops all over my code. I tried this:

```
return myList.Max(delegate(Region r) { if (r.EligibleForExpansion()) return r.Size; else return -1; });
```

However, that returns the Size value of the largest region, not the largest Region itself (which is what I need).

I know that my foreach code will return null if no Region meets the requirement while the Max code will give -1 (or any Region that doesn't meet the requirement); I can deal with either way.

I don't think I can just make Region IComparable, though; I have many searches for Region objects, and I need to sort by different parameters at different times, so the comparison function would be different in different searches.

I could just wrap my foreach code in a static function and call that wherever I need to search, but it seems like there should be a more elegant way to do this in C#.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`MaxBy` from moreLINQ library](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs):

```
public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
{
    return source.MaxBy(selector, Comparer<TKey>.Default);
}

public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
    if (comparer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");
    using (var sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no elements");
        }
        var max = sourceIterator.Current;
        var maxKey = selector(max);
        while (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            var candidate = sourceIterator.Current;
            var candidateProjected = selector(candidate);
            if (comparer.Compare(candidateProjected, maxKey) > 0)
            {
                max = candidate;
                maxKey = candidateProjected;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

like that:

```
var item = myList.Where(x => x.EligibleForExpansion())
                 .MaxBy(x => x.Size);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
myList.Where(r => r.EligibleForExpansion).OrderBy(r => r.Size).LastOrDefault()
```

Comment: Sorting is _O(n\*logn)_, while the problem itself is linear.

Comment: That's true, this is an inefficient solution. Its only advantage is succinctness, which is marginal considering morelinq can simply be imported and forgotten about.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548744%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) out of the box for this purpose:

```
        var item = myList
            .Where(r => r.EligibleForExpansion())
            .Aggregate((Region)null, (max, cur) => (max == null ? cur : cur.Size > max.Size ? cur : max));
```

If `Region` were a value type (which it isn't) you could wrap the initial value in a nullable, and get a null value for an empty list:

```
        var item = myList
            .Where(r => r.EligibleForExpansion())
            .Aggregate((Region?)null, (max, cur) => (max == null ? cur : cur.Size > max.Value.Size ? cur : max));
```